# Search for non-watermarked images

Tags: google-image-search

I often Google Image Search for simple images to add to my blog. For example I just searched 'lots of coffee'.

However, for certain terms (like the aforementioned one) it produces a lot of results from stock image companies, that are all obnoxiously watermarked.

I'm not interested in paying for the stock images so I'd rather just not have those results show up.

Is there a google-hack I can do avoid these images?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I cannot think of a "Google Hack" to do this I can think of two options.

1. You can try to search with Google Images under Search Tools --> Usage Rights --> Labeled for Reuse etc. This may give you a non watermarked image since it is free to be reused.
2. A second option you have is to use one of the many sites to get images, these include [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/creativecommons/by-2.0/) (or [PhotoPin](http://photopin.com/)), [Creative Commons Search](http://search.creativecommons.org/), [PixaBay](http://pixabay.com/en/), or any of the various other websites that offer free stock images.

Comment: Those are both great answers. :)

Comment: A slight variation to the first option: Use reverse image search to find the non-watermarked image.
Keep in mind, that google isn't the only one capable of reverse image searches. [TinEye](https://www.tineye.com/) could do this before google and also provides better matching results.